# How do you calculate float speed?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

My question is about fluid mechanics
Based on and I understood correctly, buoyancy after release in still water becomes a constant velocity and based on my understanding correctly and the force acting to fill is the volume in kilograms (according to Archimedes' law) so the downward forces are the weight and friction.
For example, let's say that it is a ball with a radius of 60 centimeters and a weight of 90 kilograms.
I would appreciate an explanation of how to find speed? And is depth important?

Comment: If you're talking about the equilibrium speed at which an object rises or sinks? It is a force balance between net buoyancy (ie per Archimedes), and drag force, which for the typical homework problem with a sphere you can get from the empirical correlation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient

Comment: if the object rises how i compute the speed with what you gave me?

Comment: Write the equation for balance of vertical force. Expression for net buoyancy on the left side. Expression for Drag force as a function of speed (which is unknown) on the right side. Solve the equation for speed.